# Largest entry of the inverse matrix?

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

I wonder if there is a "qualitative way" of predicting from the structure ix of the matrix $A$ which entry of $A^{-1}$ will be the largest. I am specially interested in the case
that $A$ is a symmetric $M$-matrix (and so $A^{-1}$ entrywise nonnegative).

There are many nice results like this for the zero pattern so I have some hope something might be possible.

Comment: I removed a tag "mat" since I assume it was created in error. Appologies if this should have some meaning that escapes me.  

Comment: @quid: Thanks. The "mat" was, obviously, a miscarried "matrices". 

Comment: Are you interested in the *size* of the largest entry of $A^{-1}$, or its *location*? If the latter, then I don't know that I have any useful comments, unless $A$ is nearly diagonal or something strong.

Comment: @GregMartin: Only the location (this time). 